# how to change debug level of a class which is in external jar

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need to change logging level of a class which is in an external jar file. In that class in jar, the code is like below. What I need to do just to change logging level actually.

```
 if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
 ...
 }
```

So I want to change logging level to debug, How can I do that for the class which is an jar file?

Answer (score 2):

Use Below method to check whether application contain debug true/false

```
    private static final X500Principal DEBUG_DN = new X500Principal("CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US");
    private boolean isDebuggable(Context ctx)
    {
        boolean debuggable = false;
        try
        {
            PackageInfo pinfo = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            Signature signatures[] = pinfo.signatures;

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

            for ( int i = 0; i < signatures.length;i++)
            {
                ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(signatures[i].toByteArray());
                X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(stream);
                debuggable = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().equals(DEBUG_DN);
                if (debuggable)
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            //debuggable variable will remain false
        }
        catch (CertificateException e)
        {
            //debuggable variable will remain false
        }
        return debuggable;
    }
```